# Why is there a huge lag between executed and acked in storm topology

Tags: apache-storm

I am working on apache storm , i see there is a huge difference between executed and acked .

Following is the screenshot from Storm UI

[image]

What can we do to make acks equal to executed , i tried increasing the number of packers but that was of no help

Answer (score 0):

to make it clear, I would like try to explain the two values' meaning. "Executed" represents how many times execute method is called for the bot. "Acked" means how many times the bolt calls ack.

From the snapshot above, it means booking_bolt executes "execute" method for 23300 times and call acked only 500 times.

So maybe in bolt's execute method, ack or fail is not called everytime.

Answer (score 0):

From Michael G. Noll training :  Why does the Storm UI report seemingly incorrect numbers?

Storm samples incoming tuples when computing statistics in order to increase performance.
Sample rate is configured via topology.stats.sample.rate.
0.05 is the default value
Here, Storm will pick a random event of the next 20 events in which to increase the metric count by 20.  So if you have 20 tasks for that bolt, your stats could be off by +/- 380.
1.00 forces Storm to count everything exactly

This gives you accurate numbers at the cost of a big performance hit.  For testing purposes however this is acceptable and often quite helpful.